# How can i reuse my javascript slider more than once on the same page?

Tags: javascript

I am learning my way around javascript and would be grateful for some advice regarding the javascript slider i have made for my test site. The slider itself works fine, my main question is how can i reuse it again on the same page without it conflicting with the first instance?

Apologies if this is a daft question I'm just not too sure, all my markup is below. If there is a better way for me to write my javascript code id be more than open to changing it.

```js
(function() {
  const card = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
  const cards = document.querySelector('.cards');
  const img = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
  let currentSlide = 0;
  let transition = window.innerWidth;

  cards.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    let element = e.target;

    if (element.classList.contains('btn--prev') && !(currentSlide == 0)) {
      img[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
      currentSlide--;
      img[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    }

    if (element.classList.contains('btn--next') && !(currentSlide == card.length - 1)) {
      img[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
      currentSlide++;
      img[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
    }

    cards.style.transform = `translate3d(${(transition * currentSlide)}px, 0, 0)`;
    cards.style.transition = '1s';
  });

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    transition = window.innerWidth;
    cards.style.transform = `translate3d(${(transition * currentSlide)}px, 0, 0)`;
    cards.style.transition = 0;
  });
}());
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.img__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s 1.1s;
}

.img.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.img--1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/wrev1ljvQ6KlfyljCQG0_lion.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521651201144-634f700b36ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489084917528-a57e68a79a1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534759846116-5799c33ce22a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--5 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500349812227-3264f5f54181?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.cards__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.card__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 23rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: .95;
}

.btns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="img__wrapper">
    <div class="img img--1 active"></div>
    <div class="img img--2"></div>
    <div class="img img--3"></div>
    <div class="img img--4"></div>
    <div class="img img--5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards__wrapper">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>02</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>03</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>04</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>05</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have this code running inside an IFFE, if you want to have multiple sliders using the same code you should look into creating a slider class and then you can create multiple instances of that class for each one of your sliders.

Comment: @JasonMcFarlane thanks for that, I am looking at taking it out of the IFFE i just put it in there for now as there is only one instance at the moment. I shall take a look at how to create a class, not done that before but it does sound like what I am after. Appreciate your reply, thank you

Comment: @rufus just wrap each slider in a div with a specific id and then use this id to get childs...

Answer (score 1):

Use classes to achieve this.

You will have to dig in a bit further but to kick start you a bit this is the strategy I would normally take. You create your class which houses all your logic and pass in the slider element you want to work with the class. This will scope your class to a specific slider.

Make sure though when you are doing your query selection to use `this.el.querySelector` instead of document to maintain the scope

**Create your class**

```
class Slider(el) {
    constructor(el) {
        this.el = el
    }

    /** 
        Slider logic
    **/
}
```

**Instantiate your class**

```
const slider1HTML = document.querySelector('#slider1')
const slider1 = new Slider(slider1HTML)
```

Now you have a slider that is scoped to slider1 and wont effect any other instances

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your logic in a scoped loop. You have to modify the css I guess. I added a class `slider` so you have to work out this too.

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.slider').forEach(function(slider){

    let card = slider.querySelectorAll('.card');
    let cards = slider.querySelector('.cards');
    let img = slider.querySelectorAll('.img');
    let currentSlide = 0;
    let transition = window.innerWidth;

    cards.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

      let element = e.target;

      if (element.classList.contains('btn--prev') && !(currentSlide == 0)) {
        img[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
        currentSlide--;
        img[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
      }

      if (element.classList.contains('btn--next') && !(currentSlide == card.length - 1)) {
        img[currentSlide].classList.remove('active');
        currentSlide++;
        img[currentSlide].classList.add('active');
      }

      cards.style.transform = `translate3d(${(transition * currentSlide)}px, 0, 0)`;
      cards.style.transition = '1s';
    });

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(cards) {
      transition = window.innerWidth;
      cards.style.transform = `translate3d(${(transition * currentSlide)}px, 0, 0)`;
      cards.style.transition = 0;
    });
    
  });
}());
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.img__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: opacity 0s 1.1s;
}

.img.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.img--1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/wrev1ljvQ6KlfyljCQG0_lion.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1521651201144-634f700b36ef?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--3 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1489084917528-a57e68a79a1e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534759846116-5799c33ce22a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.img--5 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)), url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1500349812227-3264f5f54181?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60");
}

.cards__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.cards {
  position: relative;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 1s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.card__wrapper {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50rem;
  height: 23rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  opacity: .95;
}

.btns {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4rem;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <div class="img__wrapper">
    <div class="img img--1 active"></div>
    <div class="img img--2"></div>
    <div class="img img--3"></div>
    <div class="img img--4"></div>
    <div class="img img--5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards__wrapper">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>02</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>03</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>04</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>05</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="slider">
  <div class="img__wrapper">
    <div class="img img--1 active"></div>
    <div class="img img--2"></div>
    <div class="img img--3"></div>
    <div class="img img--4"></div>
    <div class="img img--5"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="cards__wrapper">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>02</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>03</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>04</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card__wrapper">
        <div class="card">
          <span>05</span>
          <div class="btns">
            <span class="btn btn--prev">Prev</span>
            <span class="btn btn--next">Next</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```